# Probability of an infinite sequence of coin flips having heads occurring log_2(k) times consecutively, where k is the number of flips before the run

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider an infinite sequence of fair coin flips. I am interested in the event $C$, which is defined as follows: there are infinitely many occurrences of consecutive heads of length $\log_2(k)$, where k is the index of the first head in each run.

Mathematically,
\begin{equation}
C = (Y_{k+1} = Y_{k+2} = ... = Y_{k+\log_2(k)} = H \text{ i.o.})
\end{equation}

I would like to find the probability of event $C$. I have tried using the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, but constructing a sequence of independent events or evaluating the sum of probabilities has proven to be challenging. Are there any alternative approaches or theorems that I could use to find the probability of event $C$?

I was thinking considering the complement of the set $C'$, looking for an independent subset of $C'$, $A$, then using that information to show $P(A)=1$ with Borel-Cantelli Lemma part 1 which would imply $P(C')=1$ and thus $P(C)=0$. This idea was rather difficult due to the dependent nature of each even on the index of the flip

Please give some hint before or without a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Note: Find the probability of the following, where $c>1$,
\begin{equation}
B_c = (Y_{k+1} = Y_{k+2} = ... = Y_{k+c\log_2(k)} = H \text{ i.o.})
\end{equation}
is a lot easier due to the nature of the sum of $(1/2)^c\log_2(k)$ being finite for infinite terms thus Borel-Cantelli Lemma part 1 is usable. The sum of $(1/2)\log_2(k)$ is divergent, thus Borel-Cantelli Lemma part 2 possible directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Example 4.14 of Billingsly Probability and Measure and the probability is one. Throughout to light the notation let $r(k)= \lfloor \log_2(k)\rfloor$.  Let $B_k = (Y_{k+1}= \cdots = Y_{k+r(k)} = H)$. These events are evidently dependent so we cannot apply Borel-Cantelli-2 directly to them. Define a subsequence starting from 1, $n_k$, so that $n_k = n_{k-1}+ \log_2(n_{k-1})$. Then $B_{n_k}$ are indepednent events. We aim to show that

$$
P( B_{n_k} \; i.o ) = 1. 
$$

$P(B_{n_k} ) = 2^{-r(n_k)}$. So, due to $n_{k+1}-n_k = r(n_k)$ and $r(\cdot)$ being an increasing sequence,

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(B_{n_k}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-r(n_k)}=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-r(n_k)} \frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{r(n_k)} \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}} \frac{2^{-r(n)}}{r(n)}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{2^{-r(k)}}{r(k)} \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1 }{k \log_2(k)}.
$$

The first inequality comes from the fact that since $r(k)$ is increasing, for all $n \ge n_k$,
$$\frac{2^{-r(n)}}{r(n)} \le \frac{2^{-r(n_k)}}{r(n_k)}.  $$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}} \frac{2^{-r(n)}}{r(n)} \le 2^{-r(n_k)} \frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{r(n_k)}. 
$$
Further notice that since $r(k) \le \log_2(k)$
$$\frac{2^{-r(k)}}{r(k)} \ge \frac{2^{-\log_2(k)}}{\log_2(k)} =\frac{1 }{k \log_2(k)}. $$
Since the  sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1 }{k \log_2(k)}$ diverges, we have by Borel-Cantelli part 2 that $1=P(B_{n_k}\; i.o.) \le P(B_k \; i.o.) \le 1$.

Comment: This is a good proof idea, however im a bit confused about certain things. For instance i dont know how you jumped to than inequality, is it a common inequaility i dont know about, if so could you link its proof.  Furthermore and could you directly show =−1+2(−1) are independent?

Comment: I added more details about the inequalities. Regarding independence, notice that $B_{n_k}$ depends on $Y_{n_k+1},...,Y_{n_{k+1}}$ and $B_{n_{k+1}}$ depends on $Y_{n_{k+1}},...,Y_{n_{k+2}}$, which are independent.

Comment: Ah I understand.

Comment: I'd like to further support your argument by demonstrating that independence in the subsequence by showing each subevent is separated by at least one flip, thus they are independent due to flip independence. Would you mind if I added this edit to your response?

Comment: Go for it! It will be nice to have a very clear/detailed solution.